# Como funciona a medalha de tag de ouro e o que posso fazer com ela?

Tags: suporte, tags, tag-ouro

Recentemente ganhei a medalha de ouro de [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php):

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/php?userid=3635

Está escrito assim:

> Estes usuários podem sozinhos marcar perguntas sobre php como duplicadas e reabri-las quando necessário.

Mas se entendi bem existem condições que eu não posso fazer isso, por exemplo se eu mesmo adicionar a tag [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) na pergunta o sistema identifica e me "barra", fazendo ser obrigatório ter outros 4 votos (se entendi bem).

Como funciona de fato as medalhas de "tag" de ouro?

Comment: O que mais você quer saber? Acho que é isso aí que você já sabe :)

Comment: @bigown [O homem que sabia demais](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_Homem_Que_Sabia_Demais_(filme_de_1956))

Comment: tag ouro é exclusivo para clientes vips :P. Até parece propaganda de banco.

Comment: @rray com taxas mais altas que os cartões normais e a unica coisa que você ganha é a palavra VIP :)

Answer (score 11):

Ter a medalha de ouro em uma tag te libera um poder mágico que normalmente só moderadores tem: **O poder de usar o *dupehammer***. O *dupehammer* é um "martelo" que você pode usar para fechar uma questão como sendo duplicata com uma só martelada. Ou seja, quem possuir esse martelo de ouro, pode sozinho e de forma monocrática fechar questões.

**Mas, ouro não é diamante**, então há várias limitações a esse poder. O *dupehammer* só vai servir para fechar ou reabrir perguntas de forma monocrática se for para fechar como duplicata e só nas perguntas que tiverem a tag onde você tem o ouro. Para fechar perguntas por outros motivos que não seja duplicata, o ouro não vai te dar este superpoder - nesse caso a pergunta vai precisar dos  cinco votos que normalmente e ordinariamente seriam necessários para ser fechada, ou então do voto de algum moderador com um diamante.

Esse poder também serve para o efeito contrário. Você pode reabrir perguntas fechadas como duplicata apenas com o seu voto, mas não pode reabrir com apenas um voto perguntas que não tenham sido fechadas como duplicata ou que você não tenha a medalha de ouro da tag.

Para evitar abusos, você não pode usar o *dupehammer* em perguntas onde você mesmo tenha adicionado a tag na qual você tem o ouro. Nesse caso, novamente o seu voto será comum e cinco votos de fechamento serão necessários, a menos que algum moderador a feche **ou que um outro usuário que também tenha ouro na tag a feche**. O mesmo vale também para a reabertura.

Para obter a medalha de ouro em uma tag, você tem que ter publicado ao menos 200 respostas em perguntas com essa tag e acumular pelo menos 1000 votos a favor nessas respostas. E tem que ser em respostas, votos recebidos em perguntas ou o número de perguntas feitas com a tag não contam! Isso é uma coisa que não é nem um pouco fácil de se conseguir, e demanda bastante conhecimento técnico, tempo, participação, dedicação e experiência no site. Se você conseguiu uma medalha de ouro em uma tag é porque você provavelmente é um profundo conhecedor do tema da tag e já conhece bem as regras que regem o funcionamento do site e da comunidade, e portanto provavelmente será bastante capaz de identificar o que é ou não uma duplicata, mesmo se as duas perguntas relacionadas forem versadas de formas completamente diferentes uma da outra.

Fonte (embora esteja desatualizada quanto a alguns detalhes): https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/176034

Foto do seu *dupehammer* que peguei no link acima:

[image: foto]