# Devemos mudar a explicação das medalhas de tag?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, medalhas

Consta na atual descrição das medalhas de tag, como por exemplo, [JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/119/javascript), o seguinte:

> Obter mais de *X* **pontos**, em *Y* ou mais respostas na tag *Z* que não sejam wiki. <sub>[Adaptado]</sub>

Atualmente, diz-se que é preciso acumular "mais de X **pontos**", o que me parece meio errado, tendo em vista que o número necessário é o de **votos**, conforme diz [nessa resposta do Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5712/69296).

Portanto, sugiro trocar "pontos" para "votos", ficando:

> Obter mais de *X* **votos**, em *Y* ou mais respostas na tag *Z* que não sejam wiki.

Comment: Mas [esse FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395/401803) deixa bem claro que o critério são os pontos (diferença entre upvotes e downvotes), então acho que a resposta que vc linkou é que deve ser corrigida. Outro exemplo: no SOen a descrição da medalha diz "score": https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8905/extension-methods

Comment: Ah, agora vi que a resposta *linkada* diz "acumular **pelo menos** 1000 votos a favor", e daí a confusão. Se a pessoa nunca tomou um downvote, 1000 upvotes já dá a medalha. Mas se ela tomou 1 downvote, precisaria de 1001 upvotes para ter a medalha (mas em qualquer caso, **pelo menos** 1000 votos são necessários: com menos que isso vc não ganha a medalha em nenhuma circunstância). O "pelo menos" faz toda a diferença no texto (de qualquer forma, acho que vale a pena editar aquela resposta para deixar mais claro esse ponto).