# Porque não existe punição a moderadores? (condutas arbitrarias)

Tags: debate, moderação

Coincidência ou Perseguição, ter todas as perguntas fechadas por uma única pessoa, levando em consideração que as mesmas perguntas foram aceitas e respondidas nas outras versões do stackoverflow, inclusive por moderadores. Note que a pessoa que estou falando, distribui downvote em massa, de forma arbitraria, conforme seus "preceitos" ou aqueles que ele gosta.

Quando é que pessoas assim serão punidas? usam e abusam da alta reputação para fazer o que bem entendem.

Estou sendo prejudicado aqui e o stackoverflow disse que isso se resolve no stackoverflow em português, por que este possui 6 moderadores, então aguardo respostas dos mesmos.

Comment: Como já foi detectado que não tem nada a ver com moderação, o bloqueio foi causado por postagens de baixa qualidade, e o sistema fez o que tinha que era esperado nesse caso, para evitar que a situação piore, a conversa foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101032/discussion-on-question-by-macedo-montalvao-porque-nao-existe-punicao-a-moderador) para não poluir a pergunta. Interessados podem continuar a conversa clicando no link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tudo que acontece nas comunidades da Stack Exchange é auditorado, e não é por pessoas empregadas, e sim pela própria comunidade. Aqui no SOpt nós temos um protocolo de transparência e medidas automatizadas para os "usuários que distribuem downvote". O sistema identifica e pune-os adequadamente.

Moderadores são escolhidos pela comunidade através de [eleição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election) e o que cada um faz é visível para outro moderador.

Além disso, é bom colocar na sua pergunta algumas evidências do que está denunciando e se achar que é algo que não deve ser exposto em público você pode [entrar em contato com o suporte da própria empresa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact).

Você mesmo pode ver o que cada um está fazendo se alcançar a reputação de 10.000 pontos exigidos.

Perguntas fechadas requerem no mínimo 5 votos de 5 diferentes usuários para serem fechadas. E não precisam ser moderadores, apenas ter [no mínimo 3.000 pontos de reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)**¹**.

E para finalizar, O Stack Overflow em Português e Stack Overflow [são duas comunidades distintas uma da outra](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1/70). Cada uma tem sua moderação. As regras são as mesmas e a filosofia também, mas o que acontece no SOpt fica no SOpt e é discutido no SOpt.

---

(1) - há exceções: moderadores podem fechar e reabrir perguntas com apenas um voto, e usuários que possuem medalha de ouro em uma *tag* [podem fechar perguntas desta *tag* como duplicatas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5710/112052), também com apenas um voto.

Comment: Como já foi detectado que não tem nada a ver com moderação, o bloqueio foi causado por postagens de baixa qualidade, e o sistema fez o que tinha que fazer, a conversa foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101031/discussion-on-answer-by-cypherpotato-porque-nao-existe-punicao-a-moderadores-c) para não poluir a resposta. Interessados podem continuar a conversa clicando no link.

Comment: posso provar o contrario, mais deve haver equidade.

Comment: Não se trata de provar, dá pra ver no sistema que foi isso que bloqueou sua conta. Moderador não tem como fazer isso, o máximo que mod consegue é suspensão do site, por um determinado numero de dias, mas aí vc nem comentários conseguiria fazer. Foi passado o link pra vc entender isso logo no começo da conversa, sugiro parar um pouco de emitir informação, e começar a absorver, assim fica melhor pra todo mundo, senão vc gasta energia a toa, e se frustra com coisas que sequer estão acontecendo. Se tem algum problema específico, pode editar a pergunta daqui a uma horinha, e tratamos caso a caso.